# pandas combine rolling and resample

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, resampling, rolling-computation

I need some combination between resample and rolling functionality.
Basically I need to roll over seconds (for example, per second - count unique values in the last X seconds) while my data precision is milliseconds. So I need some records grouping per seconds (without aggregation so I won't loose any information) and then roll over them.

example:
lets say I have the following dataframe where the index has milliseconds precision timestamps and the data is categorical (code to generate the dataframe is below):

```
                         A
2019-01-01 13:00:00.060  1
2019-01-01 13:00:00.140  2
2019-01-01 13:00:00.731  1
2019-01-01 13:00:01.135  2
2019-01-01 13:00:01.344  3
2019-01-01 13:00:02.174  2
2019-01-01 13:00:02.213  3
2019-01-01 13:00:02.363  2
2019-01-01 13:00:02.951  1
2019-01-01 13:00:03.393  4
2019-01-01 13:00:03.454  4
2019-01-01 13:00:04.444  4
2019-01-01 13:00:05.123  1
2019-01-01 13:00:05.456  4
```

I want, for each round second, count the unique values in the last 2 seconds (window size = '2s').

doing with for loop will look like that:

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

idx_seconds = df.index.ceil('s').unique()
output = pd.Series(index=idx_seconds)
for s in idx_seconds:
    print(f"{s-to_offset('2s')} - {s} -> {df.loc[s-to_offset('2s'):s, 'A'].to_list()}")
    output [s] = df.loc[s-to_offset('2s'):s, 'A'].nunique()
```

The code will split and group the records as follow (code output):

```
2019-01-01 12:59:59 - 2019-01-01 13:00:01 -> [1, 2, 1]
2019-01-01 13:00:00 - 2019-01-01 13:00:02 -> [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
2019-01-01 13:00:01 - 2019-01-01 13:00:03 -> [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1]
2019-01-01 13:00:02 - 2019-01-01 13:00:04 -> [2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4]
2019-01-01 13:00:03 - 2019-01-01 13:00:05 -> [4, 4, 4]
2019-01-01 13:00:04 - 2019-01-01 13:00:06 -> [4, 1, 4]
```

and the output will look like:

```
2019-01-01 13:00:01    2.0
2019-01-01 13:00:02    3.0
2019-01-01 13:00:03    3.0
2019-01-01 13:00:04    4.0
2019-01-01 13:00:05    1.0
2019-01-01 13:00:06    2.0
```

I'm looking for a more efficient solution that does not require for loop. any suggestions?

---

code to generate the dataframe:

```
timestamps = [
'2019-01-01 13:00:00.060000', #0
'2019-01-01 13:00:00.140000', #0
'2019-01-01 13:00:00.731000', #0
'2019-01-01 13:00:01.135000', #1
'2019-01-01 13:00:01.344000', #1
'2019-01-01 13:00:02.174000', #2
'2019-01-01 13:00:02.213000', #2
'2019-01-01 13:00:02.363000', #2
'2019-01-01 13:00:02.951000', #2    
'2019-01-01 13:00:03.393000', #3
'2019-01-01 13:00:03.454000', #3    
'2019-01-01 13:00:04.444000', #4
'2019-01-01 13:00:05.123000', #5
'2019-01-01 13:00:05.456000', #5
]
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1 ,4]
                  ,columns=['A'], index=pd.to_datetime(timestamps)
```

Answer (score 1):

One method from `numpy` broadcast

```
s1=idx_seconds.values
s2=(idx_seconds-to_offset('2s')).values
s=df.index.values

Outs=((s[:,None]-s2)/np.timedelta64(1, 'ns')>=0)&((s[:,None]-s1)/np.timedelta64(1, 'ns')<=0)

pd.Series([(df.A[x].nunique()) for x in Outs.T],index=idx_seconds )
2019-01-01 13:00:01    2
2019-01-01 13:00:02    3
2019-01-01 13:00:03    3
2019-01-01 13:00:04    4
2019-01-01 13:00:05    1
2019-01-01 13:00:06    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: it still requires a for loop (list comprehension), but nice approach. will check it out. 10x

Answer (score -1):

Try `df.resample('2s').nunique()`